# How to fix unresponsive picture over picture elements?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've made a website that generates dynamic content for the game LoL. 
I tried to generate a responsive image grid, as you can see [here](https://lolstats.org/HORNETDanny/euw) under the "Mastery Page" tab:

```
<img src="//lolstats.org/data/img/lol/custom/masteryback.png" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
<?php                                    
    $length = sizeof($masteries[$summoner_id]['pages'][0]['masteries']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $id = $masteries[$summoner_id]['pages'][0]['masteries'][$i]['id'];
        $ranks = 1;
        $ranks = $masteries[$summoner_id]['pages'][0]['masteries'][$i]['rank'];
        $possition = $api->getMasteryPossition($id);
        $x = $possition['x'] + 510;
        $y = $possition['y'];
        echo '<img src="//lolstats.org/data/img/lol/custom/mastery_background.png" 
            style="position: absolute; top: '. ($y - 2).'px; left: '. ($x - 2) .'px;" height="52" width="52"/>';
        echo '<img src="//lolstats.org/data/img/lol/mastery/'.$id.'.png" 
            style="position: absolute; top: '. $y .'px; left: '. $x .'px;" height="48" width="48"/>';
        echo '<h1 style="position: absolute;
            top: '.($y - 15 ) .'px; left: '. ($x +15 ).'px;">'.$ranks.'</h1>';
    }
?>
</div>
```

I read something about image maps, jQuery plugins etc., but they don't fix the problem with dynamic picture content. I tried to generate a PNG in PHP, but I don't want to generate for any user 5 or more PNGs.

Is there a smarter and easy way, to generate the Mastery Pages with a responsive x and y grid?

Comment: Well, you can calculate `top` and `left` values to percent...

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Comment: Simply. For `top` do `(your_top*100/background_img_height).'%'` and for the left do `(your_left*100/background_img_width).'%'` :)

Comment: Now im a step closer. But it does not work perfectly. I think Bootstrap is a little problem. I will comment when i uploaded the sourcode. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: No problem, anytime :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally using a table to positionate the pictures.
I is easy to edit and responsive on all devices.